# How can we fetch a prop from the component that we are using? (React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

First of all, I am not using `React-Redux`. I know it would help, but it would take too long for my team to make a transition. So, please understand that I need a solution without `React-Redux`.

What I am trying to do is, I am building a PDF extractor. I want a user to select a page of a PDF that he/she wants to extract.

I have a component called `PDFViewer` which does the rendering work.

**PDFViewer**

```
 renderPdf() {
    const {pdf, pageNo} = this.state
    const container = document.getElementById('container')

    if(this.props.selectedPage){
      console.log('selectedPage exists', this.props.selectedPage)
      pdf.getPage(this.props.selectedPage).then((page) => {
        const scale = this.calcScale(page)
        const viewport = page.getViewport(scale)
        const div = document.createElement('div')

        // Set id attribute with page-#{pdf_page_number} format
        div.setAttribute('id', `page-${(page.pageIndex + 1)}`)
        div.style.width = `${viewport.width}px`
        div.style.height = `${viewport.height}px`
        page
          .getOperatorList()
          .then((opList) => {
            const svgGfx = new window.PDFJS.SVGGraphics(
              page.commonObjs,
              page.objs
            )

            return svgGfx.getSVG(opList, viewport)
          })
          .then((svg) => {
            // If there's already rendered page, delete it.
            if (container.childNodes.length > 0) {
              container.removeChild(container.childNodes[0])
            }
            container.appendChild(svg)
            return svg
          })
      })
    } else {

      console.log('props', this.props)

      pdf.getPage(pageNo).then((page) => {
        const scale = this.calcScale(page)
        const viewport = page.getViewport(scale)
        const div = document.createElement('div')

        // Set id attribute with page-#{pdf_page_number} format
        div.setAttribute('id', `page-${(page.pageIndex + 1)}`)
        div.style.width = `${viewport.width}px`
        div.style.height = `${viewport.height}px`
        page
          .getOperatorList()
          .then((opList) => {
            const svgGfx = new window.PDFJS.SVGGraphics(
              page.commonObjs,
              page.objs
            )

            return svgGfx.getSVG(opList, viewport)
          })
          .then((svg) => {
            // If there's already rendered page, delete it.
            if (container.childNodes.length > 0) {
              container.removeChild(container.childNodes[0])
            }
            container.appendChild(svg)
            return svg
          })
      })
    }
  }

  render() {
    const {pdf, pageNo} = this.state
    const {showPagination} = this.props

    return (
      <div>
        {showPagination && (
          <PageTurner
            nextPage={this.nextPage}
            previousPage={this.previousPage}
            pageNo={pageNo}
            numPages={pdf ? pdf.numPages : 0}
          />
        )}
        <div id="container" />
      </div>
    )
```

The `PageTurner` in render just makes the user selects the page that one wants to render. `renderPdf()` is in charge of rendering it.

**NextComponent**

```
render() {
    const tableStyle = this.getTableStyle();
    const tableSettings = this.getTableSettings();
    return (
        <div>
            {//<ReferenceMenu />
            }
            <div 
              style={sideBySide}>
            <PDFViewer
                paginationCallback={this.handlePageChange}
                pdfData={this.state.pdfData}
                desiredWidth={600}
                selectedPage={2}
            />
            <TablePosition
                style={tables}
                step={this.props.step}
                pdfData={this.props.pdfData}
                tableSettings={tableSettings}
                tableStyle={tableStyle}
                fileName={this.state.fileName}
                tableSize={this.getTableSize()}
                tableOffset={this.state.tableOffset}
                desiredWidth={700}
                updateXOffset={x => this.updateXOffset(x)}
                updateYOffset={y => this.updateYOffset(y)}
                markTable={() => this.markTable()}
                setOutputLabels={(row, col, val) => this.setOuputLabels(row, col, val)}
            />
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

In my next component, it tries to render the page of the selected PDF page and align with the table that the PDF page has (the table part is not important in this question).

As you can see, I sent `selectedPage={2}` as a prop to the `PDFViewer` and this successfully renders the 2nd page of the PDF. But the value is hard coded.

My question is, how can I fetch the page number selected in `PDFViewer` (`this.state.pageNo` in `PDFViewer`) and use it in the `selectedPage={ HERE }` ?

Please help

Comment: what is **NextComponent** ? Is it **PageTurner**?

Comment: I think it would be helpful if you could provide more of the code a level above `NextComponent` and `PageTurner`. You'll likely need to keep your selected page in the state of the closest common parent, update it based on an event handler in `PageTurner`, then pass it in to `NextComponent` through props.

Comment: @Firanolfind NextComponent is not PageTurner, it's just a separate page that I try to render the selected PDF page.

Comment: @Tyler What if those components do not have a common parent? What I think I need is a way how to pass UP a prop to a parent component.

Comment: The common parent doesn't have to be an immediate parent, but somewhere they have to have a common ancestor if they are within the same React app even if it is the root component.You are correct that you need to pass a prop up to the parent. The way to do that is through event handlers. I wrote a quick example up here https://codesandbox.io/s/24xym1rkn0.

Comment: @Tyler Thanks a lot. Is this possible even if there are more than 2 components related? For example, I am trying to pass-up `PageTurner`'s `pageNo` to `PDFViewer` but render that in `NextComponent`. Will this work similarly to your example?

Comment: Absolutely. You just have to list the state up to the closest common ancestor. Instead of `PageTurner` having `pageNo` in its state, move `pageNo` up the component tree. Then change your `nextPage` and `previousPage` to call a function like `onPageChange`, which is then handled in the component that is holding `pageNo`. Then you can pass `pageNo` as a prop to `PageTurner`, `PDFViewer`, and `NextComponent`. I would recommend reading about lifting state here: https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took my simple example from the comments and substituted in your component names to give you a better idea of how to lift the state up the component tree. I tried to base the flow on what I could gather from the context of your problem. Again, I would recommend reading React's article [Lifting State Up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html).

```js
const PageTurner = ({ onConfirm, onPageChange, pageNo }) => (
  <div>
    <button type="button" onClick={() => onPageChange(pageNo - 1)}>
      Prev ({pageNo - 1})
    </button>
    <button type="button" onClick={() => onPageChange(pageNo + 1)}>
      Next ({pageNo + 1})
    </button>
    <button type="button" onClick={onConfirm}>
      Confirm
    </button>
  </div>
);

const PdfViewer = ({ pageNo }) => (
  <div>
    <h1>PdfViewer</h1>
    <h2>Current Page is {pageNo}</h2>
  </div>
);

const Step1 = ({ onConfirm, onPageChange, pageNo }) => (
  <div>
    <PdfViewer pageNo={pageNo} />
    <PageTurner
      onConfirm={onConfirm}
      onPageChange={onPageChange}
      pageNo={pageNo}
    />
  </div>
);

const NextComponent = ({ pageNo }) => (
  <div>
    <h1>NextComponent</h1>
    <label>Page number is {pageNo}</label>
  </div>
);
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);

    this.state = {
      pageNo: 1,
      step: 1
    };

    this.handleConfirm = this.handleConfirm.bind(this);
    this.handlePageChange = this.handlePageChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleConfirm() {
    this.setState({
      step: 2
    });
  }

  handlePageChange(pageNo) {
    this.setState(state => ({
      pageNo
    }));
  }

  render() {
    const { pageNo, step } = this.state;

    return (
      <div>
        {step === 1 && (
          <Step1
            onConfirm={this.handleConfirm}
            onPageChange={this.handlePageChange}
            pageNo={pageNo}
          />
        )}
        {step === 2 && <NextComponent pageNo={pageNo} />}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```